# Given the hash-generating script in php, how do I post the resultant hash?

Tags: php, hash, hashcode

The resultant hashcode was requested by a payments processor.  I already had most of the information they requested posting correctly, now they require this hashcode. I don't understand the format of the POST request, nor which variable the snippet of code is creating. If I run it in a form, what is the value of the hashcode?

For example `<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php ($WhatGoesHere); ?>" />`

```
<?php
$storename = "TEST_STORE"; 
$sharedSecret = "777777777777777700000000000000005555555555555555"; 
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$timezone = "CDT";
$dateTime = date("Y:m:d-H:i:s");
function getDateTime() {
global $dateTime;
return $dateTime;
}
function getTimezone() {
global $timezone;
return $timezone;
}
function getStorename() {
global $storename;
return $storename;
}
function createHash($chargetotal) {
global $storename, $sharedSecret;
$str = $storename . getDateTime() . $chargetotal . $sharedSecret;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
$hex_str.=dechex(ord($str[$i]));
}
return hash('sha256', $hex_str);
}  
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using a `POST` request? Make a form? So many options ..

Comment: What do you mean by *the next server*?

Comment: The hashcode was requested by a payments processor.  This is what I meant by the "next server."  I already had most of the information they requested posting correctly, now they require this hashcode.  I don't understand the format of the POST request, nor which variable the above code is creating.  If I run it in a form, what is the value of the hashcode? <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php ($hex_str); ?>" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 4 different options:

- Store in `SESSION`
- Store in a hidden textbox and submit via `POST`
- Store in a cookie and read out the value
- Store in a database
  permanently

I recommend **not** to use `global`

Comment: I don't understand the format of the POST request, nor which variable the snippet of code is creating. If I POST it in a form, what is the value of the hashcode?  For example, <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php ($WhatGoesHere); ?>" />

Comment: So from what I understand, the above code is generating the hashcode via the php return function.  The php return function is essentially "waiting for me to request the return data."  Given the above code, I don't understand how to turn the return data into a variable, like "$your_hash", so I can post it in the <input type=hidden ...> line.  Do I put the whole snippet of code into a function that is named by a variable $your_hash ?  Or do I simply add $your_hash = and then all of the code ?  I am having trouble creating $your_hash = returned hexcode .  Thanks again.

Comment: This appears to be the correct format to POST the hashcode created in the script:  <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo createHash($chargetotal) ?>">  I can finally see a POST result when I use this.